# Post different values with AJAX through a JS Timer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a webserver on which all my website files are stored and 2 servers on which some other services are running. In my database I have a table server rooms, server and sensor. So when I log in into my website, I get to see all the Informations saved in my Database about those 2 servers. I uploaded a file `"getCpuUsage.php"` on those 2 servers. When I login into my website I load the CPU Usage with `AJAX` from one of those Servers. The thing is how do I load different values into my AJAX? I need to define the Server path to load that `"getCpuUsage.php"` but my timer loads every time only one Server.

The thing is I'm using `"document.getElementById"` so he loads only 1 ID and not all the other one. So I tried stuff with `"for()"` but didn't worked  out....

Could you guys suggest me some better ideas then using `"document.getElementByID"`.

Thats the current JS I'm using to get the `CPU` usage of a server.

```
function AccessServer() {

    var Server = document.getElementById("Server").value;

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("Sensor");


    var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    req.open('POST', Server + 'getCpuUsage' + '.php'); 

    req.addEventListener('load', function (ef) {
        //document.getElementById("Sensor").innerHTML = ef.target.response;
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].innerHTML = ef.target.response;
    }
    });
    req.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if that is what you want but still...

**in HTML :**

```
<input class="server" type="hidden" value="http://server1" />
<input class="server" type="hidden" value="http://server2" />
<input class="server" type="hidden" value="http://server3" />
```

**in JS**

```
var servers = document.querySelelctorAll('.server');

for( var i=0; i < servers.length ; i++ ){
   var serverName = servers[i].value;
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
       req.open('POST', serverName + 'getCpuUsage' + '.php'); 
       req.addEventListener('load', function (ef) {
           for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].innerHTML = ef.target.response;
           }
       });
       req.send();
}
```

I would put the callback function outside of the for loop or use JS `function(){}.bind()` if you need to use variables like `serverName` inside the callback, but that is a different question...

Comment: I "echo" hidden inputs with the value of the server path (http://server1), so the point is to retrieve the value from those different inputs. So if I would have 10 servers my script would "echo" 10 hidden inputs with the value of the server path (http://server1..2..3..4). How do I let know my JS Script that there are 10 or 2 or whatever how much hidden inputs there are and to load every different values from those hidden inputs.

Comment: There is just only one thing. After i get the value of the hidden inputs. How do I wrtie the different CPU Usgae values from those different servers into different `<div>` tags?

`var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
       req.open('POST', serverName + 'getCpuUsage' + '.php'); 
       req.addEventListener('load', function (ef) {
           for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].innerHTML = ef.target.response;
           }
       });
       req.send();
}`

I get the "ef.target.response" and i would to write the response trough "innerhtml".

Comment: please check mark this answer! ... what is your response? (ef)

Comment: My response(ef) is this: `<h4>Server CPU usage: 1.86% </h4><div class="meter"><span style="width:1.86%"></span></div>`

Comment: a better coding practice will be to get the server to respond with bare data objects / arrays, something like `[ {usage:1.86},{usage:2.2} ]` ... and then let the client code transform this data into HTML, when you get the data in the form of html, its harder to iterate the elements (also slower) ... but anyway, or at least try to wrap both `H4` tag and `meter DIV` with another div, so that you could then iterate over the parent holders. do you have access to the serverside code?